# How to pre-filter a search in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a page that displays a bunch of items and I have a sidebar with some selects and a search field that are used to filter the items that show up.
It works fine but now I have to make a search results page.

The client gets to the search result page with a query string ?s=something
I got the search query by doing this:

```
$scope.searchTerm = $location.search().s;
```

So I thought that If I set the search field(that filters the results) value to {{searchTerm}} that would do the trick but I was wrong.

The search field shows up with the query string on it but it does not filter.

Imagine I have a product called **product x** and my search query is **venus**. All products are still being shown. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to actually implement a filter on the collection...

Comment: There is a working filter. If I delete what is inside the field and start typing myself it will filter.

Comment: Might be good to include that code in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an input similar to this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="dataFilter" class="form-control">
```

Then your repeat needs to include the ng-model as the filter like this:

```
ng-repeat="user in dataSet | filter: dataFilter"
```

Then just assign the filter you want to the $scope variable for the search filter, in this case that would be $scope.dataFilter.

Here's a plnkr example I put together for you:
http://plnkr.co/edit/isYfL6mVLPusc94mivGA?p=preview

Comment: @Fernando if you have your filter set up like this with the `| filter: searchTerm` it should work perfectly.

Comment: It works in that case with only one search filter.
How about this? http://plnkr.co/edit/NTlKu3vmvv2kCykdSGlb?p=preview

What would you do?

Comment: @FernandoClaussen I'm guessing you are looking to have the category selected automatically as well?

Comment: No. Just the search term for now. But everything else should work if changed.

Comment: I tryed setting `$scope.search.$ = "something"` on my controller to see what would happen and I get a bunch of errors.

Comment: OH!
I think it worked!

`$scope.search = {}; .search.$ = $location.search().s;`

Comment: I had to define $scope.search as an object before I could assign .$ to anything

Comment: One last question. Is there a way to update the query string that is at the url as the user type a new value? I don't want the user to share a url to a search result different from what he intends to share.

Comment: Nevermind. I got it working with `$scope.$watch('search.$', function(val){
        $location.search('s', val);
    });`